# C, is it possible to return a default value without warning 'void value not ignored as it ought to be'?

Tags: c

I am using GNU11.
Consider this:

```
void InitFunc(void) {

    //
    //
}

int OneFunc(int Action) {

    if (Action == OPT_INIT) {

        InitFunc(); 
        return 1;
    }
}

int OneFunc1(int Action) {

    if (Action == OPT_INIT) 
        return InitFunc();  // void value not ignored as it ought to be
    
}
```

I know precisely that for OPT_INIT case, I don't need the return at all, using OneFunc1() like a void return. Is it possible to cast before result (or other option) to get rid of that warning?

```
'void value not ignored as it ought to be'
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can do something "stupid" like `return InitFunc(), 1;` but don't do that!!. Just use your first two line version from `OneFunc`. It's much more clear....

Comment: Can you explain what is that statement? Never saw that :)))

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: You *always* need to return an `int` value from a function that is declared as returning `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By casting or otherwise altering the return value of `InitFunc()`, the warning ***"void value not disregarded as it ought to be"*** in the context of `OneFunc1()` cannot be removed.

`OneFunc1()` returns a value with a return type of `int`, whereas `InitFunc()` returns nothing with a return type of void. As a result, this notice is shown. You are trying to return the result of `InitFunc()` from `OneFunc1()`, which is against C's rules, and this is an attempt to return a void value.

You can either modify the code to return an `int` value rather than calling `InitFunc()` to avoid the warning, or you can change the return type of `OneFunc1()` to `void ()`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
int OneFunc1(int Action) {
    if (Action == OPT_INIT) {
        InitFunc();
        return -1;
    }
    return 0; // you need return for all cases
}
```

You want to economize 1-2 lines?

Or this:

```
int OneFunc1(int Action) {
    if (Action == OPT_INIT)
        InitFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> C, is it possible to return a default value without warning 'void value not ignored as it ought to be'?

No. `void` returns void, not any value.